# i want to show road effect in cocos2D based game (like a bike is moving on road) iphone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

i am unable to show road effect in cocos2D based game and also little bit confused about image. what type of image i have to use to show effect and how i can use this image in code to generate moving road effect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You need to move the background back in different layers or you can use parrallax node .

Here is a link for the  by  [source code](http://cocos2d-central.com/files/file/2-source-code-for-the-learn-iphone-and-ipad-cocos2d-game-development-book/) steffen ittereheim which describes in detail the process